# I need to make this capsule in blender with particles inside animating out as the capsule opens. How can I make the capsule look similar to image?

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, animation-nodes, 3d-manipulator, blenderkit

[image]

Need to make the capsule look like the reference

Comment: Which part do you have trouble with? Modelling the shape? Setting up the lighting? Defining a similar material? Doing the animation? How far did you get? Can you show what you have? Can you explain in which way the result is different from what you want? Try to avoid the impression that you are looking for somebody to do the work for you for free please.

Comment: I am not trying to find someone who can do it for free. I am just asking for guidance on how to do it. How should I set up the lighting and material so that the capsule matches the reference image.

Comment: You say that you want to know how to do the material but looks like you want advice for the animation as well? It could be done with particles, also fluids

Comment: Alright.....but what about lighting thr capsule. How to light it up so that the smaller details of the capsule like partition line is visible?

Comment: What kind of lighting do you have which hides the details? What do you have? Can you show it? Showing your own efforts would nicely avoid the impression that you want others to do all the work.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1efmQqCIVY0enVkl31gfEK-HGAWRH__lH?usp=sharing

Comment: this is the render image of my progress and it also has my blender file. U can open it and maybe give me some feedback. I have reduced the particles and uploaded it so that its not too heavy. Thanks

Comment: @AnoushkaSrivastava Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: So you don't want to know about animation, only material?

Comment: Yes only the lighting part.

Comment: Yes, how do I match the color of the particles to the reference

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try:

[image]

Create 2 pill shapes, one for the pill itself, the other one for the powder:

[image]

For the pill, give it a material that is a mix between *Glossy* and (colored) *Transparent*, with a *(Input) Layer Weight*, if you use Eevee don't forget to choose *Blend Mode > Alpha Blend*, also plug a *Noise Texture* into a *Bump* node to create a bit of bumps:

[image]

For the powder a *Noise Texture* node plugged into a *ColorRamp*:

[image]